# Want flexbox images to increase size according to screen and stick to each other

Tags: html, css

So i have a container with three images, these images show up in a row, i want the images to stick to each other with only 5% gap in between them on all screen sizes( bigger screens ).And also the first and third image should stick to the browser wall. I tried this css but it doesnt work, the images gets too much gap in between and also the size of the images dont change according to screen size.

Like this:
[image: Expected output]

```css
.three-main {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.three-child {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.three-two {
  flex: 0 0 45%;
  height: 600px;
}

.three-two img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.three-one img,
.three-two img,
.three-three img {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.51;
}

.three-one img {
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

.three-three img {
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="three-main">
  <div class="three-child">
    <div class="three-one">
      <img src="https://borah.link/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/SAJ-51-4.png">
    </div>
    <div class="three-two">
      <img src="https://borah.link/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/SAJ-66-3.png">
    </div>
    <div class="three-three">
      <img src="https://borah.link/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/SAJ-141-2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried lots of things but nothing worked.

Comment: I am a bit confused about what you actually want. How do you want the images to look? Is all of each image always to be seen or, as the aspect ratio of the viewport changes, should bits of each image be cut off to fit (this probably doesn't make sense for images which are mainly faces) or does the whole thing shrink vertically so all of each image can be seen etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS needs to be changed, I changed it to use grid instead of flex and height of first and third image is fixed. You can change it based on device using media query.

```css
.three-main {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.three-child {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2.5fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 10px;
  align-items:center;
}

.three-two {
  flex: 0 0 45%;
  height: 600px;
}

.three-two img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.three-one img,
.three-two img,
.three-three img {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.51;
}

.three-one img {
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
.three-one img, .three-three img {
  height: 33rem;
}

.three-three img {
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="three-main">
  <div class="three-child">
    <div class="three-one">
      <img src="https://borah.link/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/SAJ-51-4.png">
    </div>
    <div class="three-two">
      <img src="https://borah.link/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/SAJ-66-3.png">
    </div>
    <div class="three-three">
      <img src="https://borah.link/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/SAJ-141-2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This distorts the outer images as the viewport narrows.